# The voltage created in the transformer

Tags: transformer, power-engineering

The voltage generated in the transformer must be due to the change in the flux in the coils, but if the voltage is DC, why is no voltage induced?

Of course, we know that voltage is created by the derivative of flux, but what does it mean?

Comment: With DC, the flux is constant, so change  in flux (derivative of flux) is constant also.

Comment: Just to clarify what @mkeith said, the derivative of flux is zero for DC.

Comment: @mkeith apart from mathematical discussion and solving the equation, what is its meaning and understanding?

Comment: @JohnD apart from mathematical discussion and solving the equation, what is its meaning and understanding?

Comment: If you consider a transformer, a steel core with copper windings, magnetic flux is created when voltage is applied to one of the windings. Any time that flux changes, a voltage will also be created on the other winding. Why? There is no why. Why does the gravitational force exist? Nobody knows why. But we do know it exists.

Comment: @mkeith I wouldn't say there *is* no why, but the why is more a question for physics SE than here, I imagine.

Comment: @Hearth there is always a point where the answer is either "there is no why" or "nobody knows why... that is just how the universe works."

Comment: Derivative is (in simple terms) the rate of change over time.  If there’s no change then the derivative is zero.  On the other hand, at high frequencies the derivative is high and so even a small transformer can deliver quite a significant amount of power.  For this reason switch-mode designs tend to use much higher than mains frequency.

Comment: @Frog, power is the combination of voltage and current, irrespective of frequency. (Power out) = (power in) minus losses, almost independent of frequency (losses can vary with frequency). Higher frequencies will produce higher voltages, but that's only one factor of power delivery.

Comment: @pdtcaskey power is indeed the combination of power and current, but that doesn’t explain why passing DC through a transformer primary will yield nothing on the secondary.  I think you’ve missed the point of my comment, which seeks to explain what a derivative is in mathematical terms.

Comment: @Frog: absolutely agree with your main point; I should have noted that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason we cannot use a transformer at DC is that a DC voltage would cause a linearly increasing flux in the core: \$\Phi\sim\frac{\mathrm d V}{\mathrm d t}\$. In reality, the core will [saturate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_(magnetic)) quickly, and the flux stops increasing. Then, also the current in the primary coil reaches a limit by the DC resistance of the winding.

Comment: I disagree that DC necessarily saturates a core. The core becomes saturated only when the magnetic fields of the spinning electrons in the core are all aligned with the applied magnetic field, so that additional magnetic force produces no additional alignment. That process happens whether the voltage will be oscillating or remaining constant. In AC, the saturation will cease once the magnitude of the field decreases again. One can vary the strength of an electromagnet by varying the applied DC voltage (until the core saturates). A "low" DC voltage still produces no voltage in a transformer.

Answer (score 1):

> *but if the voltage is DC, why is no voltage induced?*

It's all a matter of timing, idealities, definitions and perspective.

If you take a regular AC mains transformer of primary inductance circa 10 henry and turns ratio (say) 10:1 then, apply 1 volt to the primary terminals, you will see 0.1 volts induced across across the secondary terminals. This might last for a second or two but, then erodes to zero.

If the transformer was ideal (except for its primary inductance of 10 henry) then you might see 0.1 volts induced across the secondary for maybe 20 seconds or more but then, that voltage erodes to nothing due to the primary current becoming so high (2 amps or more) that the input 1 volt DC supply goes into current limit.

- Can you accept a steady voltage that lasts maybe up to 20 seconds is DC?
- Can you accept that a non-ideal transformer might only produce DC for a couple of seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically speaking, "derivative" means "rate of change". In *steady state*, DC does not change, the magnitude of the flux does not change, and the "derivative" = 0, so induced voltage is zero, and the "transformer" is reduced to the role of an electromagnet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might not understand a basic property of transformers, related to the term `Flux`.  Flux is `change`.  An AC voltage is one that changes.  A DC voltage is one that stays steady (does not change).

If you apply a changing AC voltage to one winding, the flux (change) in the voltage allows the transformer to propagate energy into the other winding, and you get an output AC voltage.  If you apply a steady DC voltage to one winding, the lack of flux prevents the transformer from propagating energy into the other winding, and you do not get an output voltage.

Comment: This is incorrect. A DC voltage applied at the primary will produce a linearly ramping-up flux and this will induce a constant voltage in the secondary. Of course this cannot last forever but, if the applied voltage is low and, the primary inductance is high you will see this for a few seconds.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, a **transition** from *0* Volts DC to *some* Volts DC (or vice versa) does transfer energy through the transformer, but that's a voltage change.  The question was clearly asking about conditions where no voltage was appearing in the transformer output, and I was giving another description of why.

Comment: No, that is also incorrect. If you apply a DC voltage to an inductor, the flux rises linearly until the DC source runs out of amps.

Comment: Flux is the density of the magnetic field, regardless of whether its magnitude varies. The magnitude of voltage induced in the secondary winding is proportional to the rate of change of the magnitude of the flux density (although the magnitude of that proportion varies with the saturation level of the core).